# How to disable UILocalNotification in iPhone for some time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I have implemented one reminder iphone applicaion in which I have used local notification for reminder.

In this application their one functionality alert on/off.

So when user set on then user get notification and if its off then user can get notification.

I have done googling but not got sucess.

Can you give me idea for that is it possible or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: disabling local notification means kinda snoozing or removing the notification..??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other notifications in your appln.

If you don't have other notification in your app than,

Do one thing,

When you set OFF 
- cancel all the notification
- calculate the time difference of current time & your notification firing time. set this in to some variable.

when you set it ON 
- reschedule your Notification based on the time which you have saved earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you know how UISwitch works, according to switch position

```
      UILocalNotification *localNotif;
     //if switch is on 
     localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    //else if localNotif is not equal to null then 
     localNotif = nil;
```

You can start a timer which continuously check switch position and do the above stuff that depends on your coding.